# Get corresponding key from an array value

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, key

I have a hash whose values are arrays:

```
@@words = {
    "direction" => ["north", "south", "west"],
    "verb" => ["go", "jump"]
  }
```

If I do `@@words.key("north")`, it will return `error` rather than `direction`. How do I get this to work properly?

Comment: Must "north" be the first element of the array or any element of the array?

Comment: @CarySwoveland OP is looking for identifying a key if  given a member of the array value - it should return `"direction"` for `"south"` as well

Comment: James, please answer. @Wand, I think it could be interpreted either way.  Suppose `words = { "Jones" => ["Bob", "chief underling"], "Cher" => ["", "singer and actor"]`. and you wanted the person with no first name.

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: I asked a very simple question. When you did not answer, I asked again. Again, you did not answer. Did you never learn manners?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@@words.find { |_, value| value.include? 'north' }.first
```

Comment: Do you have the `tick` icon to hypnotise OP to accept your answer?  Or trick people to upvote your answer thinking its an accepted answer?  It sure works in 2nd case :-)

Comment: @WandMaker, you underestimate human beings. It is just the most correct and on the point solution atm. :)

Comment: Whats the purpose of the underscore btw? Why can't it be |k,v|, I thought those were just placeholder terms? So why does |underscore, value| have to be used? @ndn

Comment: @JamesMitchell, it's an idiom. I could have used `key` there, but the convention goes that if you are not interested in something, you should name it `_` (as the case here, I'm not directly accessing the `key` variable).

Comment: @Wand, the technical term is "[subliminal stimuli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subliminal_stimuli)".

Comment: @CarySwoveland And it has already made OP to accept the answer :-)

Comment: @Wand, something like [this](http://lowres.jantoo.com/entertainment-hypnotised-guilty_verdicts-judges-trails-hypnotist-16514979_low.jpg)?

Comment: @ndn while I up voted on the basis of your solution I think you over estimate humanity and under estimate the power of suggestion. Almost all successful, full scale, marketing campaigns start with an idea of how they want their product or company to be perceived and they build around that rather than the product itself (e.g. Pharmaceuticals). In your case your product is your answer and using a green check in the same fashion SO does causes a perception of correctness whether or not this was you intention. Visual perception is more immediate than cognitive processing to help keep us alive.

Comment: @engineersmnky, again, these are assumptions. An experiment can be conducted. Try to use a generic picture for a month. Then use a green tick sign for a month. Then use a red x mark for a month. As long as your answers remain consistent, I would guess there would be no statistically significant difference. Some of my answers are upvoted, some are accepted, some are ignored. It really mainly depends on the relevance and correctness of a given answer. Also, what if it has the opposite effect? Maybe people subconsciously feel tricked and are in fact less likely to approve of a tick sign.

Comment: @engineersmnky, ofc, if you are willing to conduct such an experiment, you should think of an objective way to retrospectively measure progress (**reputation_gained** - **bounty_reputation**) / **#answers** sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

```
@@words = {
    "direction" => ["north", "south", "west"],
    "verb" => ["go", "jump"]
  }

@@words.find { |_,(v,*_)| v == "north" }
  #=> ["direction", ["north", "south", "west"]] 

or 

@@words.find { |_,(v,*_)| v == "north" }.first
  #=> "direction"
```

depending on your requirements. I'm assuming "north" is to be the first element of the value array.

A variant:

```
@@words.keys.find { |k| @@words[k].first == "north" }
```

You asked about the block variables in:

```
@@words.find { |_,(v,*_)| v == "north" }
```

I've used a combination of parallel assignment and *decomposition* (or *disambiguation*, a term I find somewhat homely). We have:

```
enum = @@words.find
  #=> #<Enumerator: {"direction"=>["north", "south", "west"],
  #                  "verb"=>["go", "jump"]}:find>
```

The two elements of `enum` that will be passed to the block can be seen by converting it to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [["direction", ["north", "south", "west"]],
  #    ["verb", ["go", "jump"]]]
```

When the first value of `enum` is passed to the block, the block variables are set like so:

```
k,(v,*rest) = enum.next #=> ["direction", ["north", "south", "west"]] 
k                       #=> "direction" 
v                       #=> "north" 
rest                    #=> ["south", "west"]
```

I won't be using `k` or `rest` in the block calculation, so I've chosen to replace both with the local variable `_`, mainly to draw attention to the fact that that those variables are not being used, but also to reduce the chance of error in the block calculation.

Incidentally, there's no point in using a class variable outside of a class, and little reason for using one at all. It's generally (always?) preferable to use a class instance variable than a class variable. If you are not familiar with the former, that will be a lesson for another day.

Comment: Okay I'll give it a try. Would you care to explain the _,(v,*_) syntax. I want to try to learn exactly what this answer does.

Comment: I believe the OP wants the key for a value contained in the array e.g. 'south' would still return "direction" as would 'west' but 'jump' would return "verb". That being said bravo on the syntax exploitation.

Comment: If I use `"south"` instead of `"north"`, then, I get `undefined method 'first' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` in the 3rd variant

Comment: @engineersmnky and Wand, not necessarily. See my comments on the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Enumerable#select`

```
@@words
=> {"direction"=>["north", "south", "west"], "verb"=>["go", "jump"]}
@@words.select { |_, v| v.include?("north") }
=> {"direction"=>["north", "south", "west"]}
@@words.select { |_, v| v.include?("north") }.keys
=> ["direction"]
```

An alternative with `map`:

```
@@words.map { |k, v| k if v.include?("north") }.compact
=> ["direction"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Some monkey patching to rescue :-)

```
words = {
    "direction" => ["north", "south", "west"],
    "verb" => ["go", "jump"],
    "test" => "me"
}

class Hash 
  def key_ (value)
    key(value) || key(self.select { |k, v| v.include?(value)}.values.first)
  end
end

puts words.key_("south")  # direction
puts words.key_("go")     # verb
puts words.key_("me")     # test
```

`self.select { |k, v| v.include?(value)}.values.first` represents the array in which `value` is present, so that now we can use built-in [`Hash#key` method](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-key) to find the key.

The code also takes care of scenario when values of Hash are not all arrays by invoking `key(value)` first, and if it is `nil`, then, it try again thinking may be `value` is present in one of the `Hash#values` as an array member.

This solution can be extended to include nested hashes, and other data types.